# SDTT shows the 'Question', but not the 'Answer'

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

For a FAQ, I try to combine HTML, WAI-ARIA and Microdata (using Schema.org), but the SDTT validation just shows the `Question`, not the `Answer`.

```html
<section class="accordion" role="tablist" aria-live="polite">
    <details>
        <summary aria-controls="panel0" role="tab" itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
            <p temprop="name">How to beat the boss...spoiler alert !</p>
            <meta itemprop="answerCount" content="1"/>
        </summary>
            <div itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                <p aria-labelledby="tab0" role="tabpanel" itemprop="text"> Just aim to the red spots near his eyes Keep shooting at these spots until the eyes open, then hit quickly both eyes with your laser beam.</p>
           </div>
    </details>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SDTT shows the `Answer`, but it’s on the same level as the `Question` (so they are not associated).

The reason for this is that you didn’t add the `Answer` to the `Question`, but to the parent item (which is missing in your snippet).

The `div` with the `acceptedAnswer` property needs to be a child of the element with the `Question`. If that’s not possible with your markup (because the `Answer` shouldn’t be part of the `summary` element), you could make use of Microdata’s `itemref` attribute:

```html
<details>

  <summary aria-controls="panel0" role="tab" itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Question" itemref="answer">
    <p temprop="name">How to beat the boss...spoiler alert !</p>
    <meta itemprop="answerCount" content="1"/>
  </summary>

  <div id="answer" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
    <p aria-labelledby="tab0" role="tabpanel" itemprop="text"> Just aim to the red spots near his eyes Keep shooting at these spots until the eyes open, then hit quickly both eyes with your laser beam.</p>
  </div>

</details>
```

(I added `itemref="answer"` to the `Question`, and `id="answer"` to the `Answer`.)